# How to convert a dataframe into a dictionary with row and column as keys in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe constructed by the following data and function

```
model.Crops = ["barley", "rapeseed", "wheat"]
model.FixedInputs = ["land", "labor", "capital"]
Beta =  [[0.3, 0.1, 0.3],\
        [0.2, 0.1, 0.2],\
        [0.3, 0.1, 0.2]]

pd.DataFrame(data=Beta_F_Data, index=model.Crops, columns=model.FixedInputs)
```

I got this matrix:

```
FixedInputs  land  labor  capital
Crops                            
barley        0.3    0.1      0.3
rapeseed      0.2    0.1      0.2
wheat         0.3    0.1      0.2
```

How can I convert this matrix into a dictionary with index and columns as keys?

I tried df.to_dict(), but it only uses columns as keys.

It should look like this:

```
dict = {(barley, land): 0.3, (barley, labor): 0.1, ...(wheat, capital):0.2}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to `stack` before calling `to_dict`

```
df.stack().to_dict()

Out[389]:
{('barley', 'land'): 0.3,
 ('barley', 'labor'): 0.1,
 ('barley', 'capital'): 0.3,
 ('rapeseed', 'land'): 0.2,
 ('rapeseed', 'labor'): 0.1,
 ('rapeseed', 'capital'): 0.2,
 ('wheat', 'land'): 0.3,
 ('wheat', 'labor'): 0.1,
 ('wheat', 'capital'): 0.2}
```

Comment: Nice use of `stack` here!

Comment: why is stack so amazing here? what else can stack do?

Comment: Main purpose of `stack` is used to pivot dataframe. Anytime you think you need to pivot a `df` in some ways, `stack` may be an option. `stack` will create `multiindex` series or dataframe. Multiindex gets converted by `to_dict` into `tuple` keys. I use this feature of `stack` to create dict as your desired output. Possibilities of using `stack` is vast.